# Why does one query return related entities, but not the other?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm currently migrating existing repositories to a generic one.

The existing method to retrieve a list of all MyEntity from the database looks like:

```
public IList<MyEntity> GetAll()
{
    var list = _context.MyEntity.Include(_ => _.OtherEntity).ToList();
    return list;
}
```

This method would return a list of all MyEntity, plus load their related OtherEntites.
I've simplified the repository in to a generic one, whose method looks like this:

```
public IList<TEntity> GetAll(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] expressions)
        {
            var entity = _context.Set<TEntity>();
            foreach (var expression in expressions)
            {
                entity.Include(expression);
            }
            var list = entity.ToList();
            return list;
        }
```

And I would call the method like this:
`var myEntityList = _repository.GetAll(_ => _.OtherEntity);`

However this does not seem to load the related OtherEntites. I've had to include the expression parameter for scenarios where loading related entities may or may not be needed.

Could someone explain where I've gone wrong and why my related entities won't load in the new setup? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the first method returns the result of `.Include()` while the second method just calls the method, but ignores the result. LINQ methods usually return a new collection rather than modify the existing collection.

Try this:

```
public IList<TEntity> GetAll(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] expressions)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> entity = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    foreach (var expression in expressions)
    {
        entity = entity.Include(expression);
    }
    var list = entity.ToList();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried this but it gives an error because the type `IIncludableQueryable` is not assignable to type `DbSet`

Comment: @d1s use `IQueryable<TEntity> entity = _context.Set<TEntity>();`, while you're at it you should call your variable `query` not `entity` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Update: I changed the first line to be `var entity = _context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking()` and it fixed the issue by returning an `IQueryable`, seems like a win-win as I didn't need them to be tracked for this method. I'm curious as to how to return an `IQueryable` without using a method like `AsNoTracking()` though.

Comment: @joakimriedel thanks for your tip, you've just answered my previous comment :)

Comment: @d1s :) you could also check `AsQueryable()`.

Comment: @joakimriedel Thanks for catching my oversight. I've edited my answer per your initial suggestion.